# Leaflet Marker autoPan option

Tags: leaflet

According to the Leaflet docs the marker's *autoPan* option works like this:

> Set it to true if you want the map to do panning animation when marker
>   hits the edges.

What does 'the marker hits the edges' mean?

When I set the option to true and add a new marker right on the edge or outside of the current view, the map does not automatically move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `autoPan` option of `L.Marker` dates back to https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/5651 - as you would be able to see, it implements https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3572 , which is about automatically panning the map when **dragging** a **draggable marker** near the edge of the map viewport.

Comment: Makes sense. So this should work if I set both *draggable* and *autoPan* to true?

As in:
var m = L.marker([0, 0], {draggable: true, autoPan: true});

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: It works now! Was using 1.2 and now updated to 1.3.3. Nice effect :-)